# IIS 10 response headers keep reverting after publishing from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, http-headers, iis-10

I follow something similar to these steps to add CORs to IIS 10 and after about 10 minutes, the response header is removed and CORs stops working.

1. Open Internet Information Service (IIS) Manager.
2. Right click the site you want to enable CORS for and go to Properties.
3. Change to the HTTP Headers tab.
4. In the Custom HTTP headers section, click Add.
5. Enter Access-Control-Allow-Origin as the header name.
6. Enter * as the header value.
7. Click Ok twice.

Then I go back to Visual Studio and publish my project. Why are my CORs response headers being removed and how do I make them stay?

Comment: Find the `web.config` file. Enable CORS and note the modified date. Wait for CORS to stop working, note the modified date. Is the file being modified?

Comment: I am publishing my code about every 10 minutes. Could that be it?

Comment: Yes! You are most likely overwriting the `web.config` is recommend you re ask your question tagging the IDE you are using and how to avoid overwriting a `web.config` when you publish code.

Comment: updated question to admit that I was publishing my project :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a strong hint from S. Walker, I went onto the server, modified the response header as desired and then looked at the web.config file.

It had added:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

So I copied that into my project web.config file and published. Now it doesn't disappear and CORs continues to work. Seems obvious now.